# Apply for checking if element in one column is included in list of other column row wise

Tags: r, apply

I want to transform the following loop into apply/lapply syntax in order to make it more efficient:

```
for (i in seq(1, nrow(df)) {
     is.element(df$a[i], unlist(strsplit(df$b[i], "/")))
}
```

I have tried this:

```
is.element(df$a, unlist(strsplit(df$b[i], "/")))
```

But it does not work because of the unlist statement.

Also tried:

```
mapply(is.element, df$a, unlist(strsplit(df$b, "/")))
```

Example of the data:

```
print(df$a)

[1] "A" "G" "T" "A" "CCG"

print(df$b)

[1] "G/A" "C/TTTTTA" "C/-" "A/G" "G/A/C"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use a regular expression:

```
mapply(\(x, y) grepl(sprintf("/?%s/?", x), y), df$a, df$b)
    A     G     T     A   CCG 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or with the `purrr` package:

```
map2_lgl(df$a, df$b, ~ any(.x == str_split(.y, "/")[[1]]))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of `unlist` will recursively unlist the string into a single vector (which is okay when we are looping as there is only a single element) and which may have a different `length` when compared to `a`, whereas if we use the `list` from `strsplit` the `length` will be same as `a` and `mapply` requires all arguments to be of same length (exception is of elements will `length`  1 which gets recycled)

```
mapply(is.element, df$a, strsplit(df$b, "/"))
  A     G     T     A   CCG 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Also, an easier vectorized option is `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(df$b, df$a)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("A", "G", "T", "A", "CCG"), b = c("G/A", 
"C/TTTTTA", "C/-", "A/G", "G/A/C")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will str_detect work if I have a = "CGC" and b = "C/G"? I want this to be returned FALSE as I want exact match.

Comment: It does not work tough the other way around: str_detect("C/TTTT/A", "T") returns TRUE but it should return FALSE.